# Use OpenApi v3 yaml to generate route and validator with Vertx

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x

I'm in Vertx 4.3.4 with RX java, and I want to initialize my routes with a openapiv3.yaml and especially (the main purpose) validate user input of each declared route in yaml (with the input model too in file).

I use a code like that:

```
router.get("/configs").handler(this.handlers.configHandler::getAll));
```

and I would like to add something like this:

```
  .handler(
    ValidationHandlerBuilder
      .create(schemaParser)
      .build()
  );
```

but I didn't found anything to get a "schemaParser" in the documentation or to create it, and all the API of the 4.3.4 was deprecated without any example to use it.
I precise that I don't have a json file for validation but a yaml and a  io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.Route of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thank a lot and best regards

Comment: You want to use the vertx-web-openapi module. The [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-openapi/java/) are really good

Comment: No sorry that don't respond to my problem, and already saw it before questionning ... sorry, is for 4.4.1 version and not precise something for schemaParser